# too many arguments in call to Find mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I was trying to search a collection with multiple field conditions using $elemMatch operator. Then I encountered an error "too many arguments in call to c.Find". Document structure is as follows:-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cfca4bf23e4e2859257425"),
    "company_name" : "bank",
    "admin" : {
        "email" : "xyz@bank.com",
        "fullname" : "xyz"
    },
    "process" : [ 
        {
            "process_name" : "Enquiry",
            "processtype" : 0,
            "sortorder" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "process_name" : "Converted",
            "processtype" : 1,
            "sortorder" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

My query is as follows:-

```
colQuerier := bson.M{"company_name": "bank"}
match := bson.M {"process": bson.M {"$elemMatch": bson.M{"process.process_name":"Converted"}}}
err := c.Find(colQuerier,match).Sort("-id").All(&results)
```

What is wrong with my query? Is it any syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because c.Find(https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Collection.Find) only allow one param

You can try

```
query := bson.M{
    "company_name": "bank",
    "process": bson.M{
        "$elemMatch": bson.M{"process.process_name":"Converted"}
    }
}
err := c.Find(query).Sort("-id").All(&results)
```

Comment: Thanks bro, but its returning errors like:-  backend/models/processmodel.go:30: syntax error: unexpected :, expecting )
backend/models/processmodel.go:31: non-declaration statement outside function body      any idea????

Comment: //First line is line 30
//c.Find(bson.M{"company_name": "bank"},"process": bson.M {"$elemMatch": bson.M{"process.process_name":"Converted"}})
//colQuerier = bson.M{"company_name": Company}
// change := bson.M {"$push": bson.M {"process": Process[0].ProcessItemMinimal}}
// err := c.Update(colQuerier,change) @Specode.. Sorry for the delay man. thanks for  you help. First line is the query you gave me. I tried it in the way you gave me. but it too didn't work.

Comment: Try to fix line 30 to: c.Find(bson.M{"company_name": "bank","process": bson.M {"$elemMatch": bson.M{"process.process_name":"Converted"}}})